# Adding a image to an expansion tile

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add an image as a leading widget to my expansion tile. Every entry of my List has a different image. I added the image path to every entry of my list but the image is not displayed.

This is my List:

```
 class Entry{
  final String title;
  final String imageUrl;
  final List<Entry> children;

  Entry(this.title, this.imageUrl, [this.children = const <Entry>[]]);
}

final List<Entry> data = <Entry>[
  Entry(
    'title', "/assets/images/picture.png",
    <Entry>[
      Entry(
        'subtitle', '/assets/images/picture.jpg',
        <Entry>[
          Entry('subtitle', '/assets/images/example.jpg' ),
          Entry('subtitle', '/assets/images/example.jpg' ),
          Entry('subtitle', '/assets/images/example.jpg' ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
];
```

this is the code of the expansion tile:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../models/entry.dart';

class EntryItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const EntryItem(this.entry);
  final Entry entry;

  Widget _buildTiles(Entry root) {
    if (root.children.isEmpty) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            border: Border.all(
              width: 2,
              color: Color.fromRGBO(3, 120, 163, 1),
            ),
          ),
          child: ListTile(
            leading: Image.asset(root.imageUrl),
            title: Text(
              root.title,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          border: Border.all(
            width: 3,
            color: Color.fromRGBO(3, 120, 163, 1),
          ),
        ),
        child: ExpansionTile(
          key: PageStorageKey<Entry>(root),
          leading: Image.asset(root.imageUrl),
          title: Text(root.title, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          children: root.children.map<Widget>(_buildTiles).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles(entry);
  }
}
```

adding the image path directly to the leading widget works but displays the same image for all tiles.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess you have added same entry subtitle line for 3 times which is resulting to this.

Comment: I've added a different image and title to every entry but this wasnt the solution. Meanwhile i got following error. "Unable to load asset: /assets/images/example.jpg" It can't be the identation in my pubspec.yaml because i'm using the images somewhere else in my app...

Comment: solved the problem...it was the beginning "/" at the image path

Comment: congratulations. :)